# Is it possible to link timer and Window_Loaded event?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

Is it possible to trigger `Window_Loaded` on the `Timer.Tick` event like this ?

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
};

timer.Tick += Window_Loaded;
timer.Start();
```

Or is there another way to do it ?

Comment: So you want to perform an action that you do when you load the window over and over again? What do you do in window_loaded that a view model can't do? If I understand what is happening here is you want to refresh window when something changes. Chances are you didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged and there is no sign on a view model. read up on binding and how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question probably confuses events and event handlers. In C#, events can only be raised from within the class they were declared in, unless they expose an `internal` or `public` method that can be called from outside. However, the [`Loaded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=net-5.0) event defined in `FrameworkElement` is not exposed that way, meaning you cannot raise it from your code.

What your code does is add your `Window_Loaded` *event handler* for the `Loaded` event, which is just a method. However, the sigatures of the corresponding `Tick` and the `Loaded` delegates do not match.

- [`Tick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=net-5.0) - [`public delegate void EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-5.0)
- [`Loaded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=net-5.0) - [`public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventhandler?view=net-5.0)

In order to add the window loaded event handler to the `Tick` event, you have to create a method or lambda that matches the `Tick` delegate and calls `Window_Loaded` with appropriate arguments, e.g.:

```
timer.Tick += OnTick;
```

```
private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var routedEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs();
   // ...set the routed event args properties.

   Window_Loaded(sender, routedEventArgs);
}
```

---

**A word of caution.** Although this might solve your problem it is most likely not the right approach for what you want to achieve. The `Loaded` event is called by the framework in the control's lifecycle.

> Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

Whatever you are doing in your `Window_loaded` event handler should not be done periodically, because that does not comply with the sematics of this event. Maybe this is an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score -2):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };

        timer.Tick += Window_Loaded;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: While technically it answers the question, `Window_Loaded` better suits the Loaded routed-event for a WPF Window. More explanation should be included.